# thingsboard- integration with my api's

Tags: thingsboard

I use thingsboard dashboard to visualize history data of devices.I installed thingsboard. now i am using their external database schema.I need to customize it according to my requirements in UI source code. I found API s are calling from app->src->ui->api folder 
How do I integrate thingsboard dashboard with my rest apis.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly the question, you are looking for API documentation/usage examples in order to use them in devloping custom elements for your dashboard.

You could start from reading the official documentation: [this](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/rest-api/)

After that, I suggest having a look at Swagger UI of your Thingsboard instance where you can explore and test all the available APIs (i.e [this](https://demo.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui.html) ).

Finally, if you need futher help I can share some code about how to get the JWT token for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is how to access the API documentation and to how to use them.

Be aware that the professional and the community editions varies in functionalities at the API, the professional one has more functions since more features.

All what you have to do is enter your address, https://(write your address)/swagger-ui.html
You will find the documentation.